# Recursive function to check if a matrix is symmetric

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, matrix, symmetric

I have an assignment to implementthe matrix class and a method that checks if the matrix is symmetric.
The method has to be recursive and then I have to calculate its complexity. After I have to transform the recursive function to its iterative version.

For now this is how my matrix class looks like:

```java
public class Matrix<T> {
    private int m, n;
    private T[][] data;

    public Matrix(int m, int n) {
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public Matrix(T[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isSymmetric() {
        if (m != n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (data[i][j] != data[j][i]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isSymmetric(int i, int j) {
        if (i < 0 && j < 0) return true;
        else {
            return isSymmetric(i - 1, j - 1);
        }
    }

    public T get(int i, int j) {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    public void set(int i, int j, T value) {
        data[i][j] = value;
    }

    public int[] getSize() {
        return new int[]{m, n};
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String rep = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            rep += "( ";
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                rep += data[i][j].toString() + "\t";
            }
            rep += ")\n";
        }
        return rep;
    }
}
```

I have a iterative version of the `isSymmetric()` function, but I cannot get the recursive one.

Answer (score 2):

You can start check from maximum `row` and `col` each recursion will be decrese it by `1` until `0`;

```
public class Matrix<T> {

    private final int height;
    private final int width;
    private final T[][] data;

    public Matrix(T[][] data) {
        height = data.length;
        width = data[0].length;
        this.data = data;   // it brakes OOP: encapsulation
    }

    public boolean isSymmetricIterative() {
        if (height != width)
            return false;

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
                if (data[row][col] != data[col][row])
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isSymmetricRecursive() {
        return isSymmetricRecursive(height - 1, width - 1);
    }

    private boolean isSymmetricRecursive(int row, int col) {
        return row < 0 && col < 0 || data[row][col] == data[col][row] && isSymmetricRecursive(row - 1, col - 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the recursive version, you forgot to add a check to see if the two elements are equal. Without it, there is no case where the method would return `false`.

```java
public boolean isSymmetric() {
    return m == n && isSymmetric(m - 1, n - 1);
}

public boolean isSymmetric(int i, int j) {
    if (i < 0 && j < 0) return true;
    else if (data[i][j] != data[j][i]) return false;
    else {
        return isSymmetric(i - 1, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) *is a square matrix that is equal to its transpose.* Let's assume that we have a *square matrix*.

To avoid unnecessary iterations and to reduce the *time complexity*, you can iterate over the indices only in the *lower left corner* of the matrix and compare the corresponding elements with those in the *upper right corner* `m[i][j]==m[j][i]`, excluding the *main diagonal*, until the first mismatch.

[image: lower left corner of the matrix]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZRNc5swEIbv/IodH1KYKjhp@jmue@8hl/jo8UHBayMFBJUWt5kMv91dMBQ7yK2nmvGA9/PVoxVa7uR1UaLR66f9XuVlYQk0G@OKVBY7sijz@LuhRfs2C4KyesxUAkkmnYN7qQy8BMBrOoUM6Y0Dtlc5AqWS4CdCKncIEtyPSlqEXJJVv9qErpAjSfzYFWrNXmVC7qTMdrkCabcu6qo3Sxlarth@qAHzI1e/Xm4FvBNwJ@C9gA@1GAcMXgEffQGDV8AnX8DgFfDZFzB4BXypa2bWuxbPjjCPi4rikjdJmQmVWzznOfKOkvCwsSiaXZjw0GUI4G3f9Hl10J@HIrQMl/nv0DpVmNbRAX8sigylgWMBp4SP2Vukyhr4MwixlWaLIfc9xMYZmi2l0YhGLLPsXlKShgquv40K3AhQ46R@TaesCG2OayUJgTGUFZ2NjkvEp1A3bTzcJmo@gbeg@DcRun3X0fnWg@624GGXS7Va6hXM5/1/vWLTGLzFpGLgF4N/eEVeNLMO6vDQJ3dgAwzy6yl1uLoCzUYVvboS/@Z3KajZSVaj4q9EPFezydFNIM8B3PoijubMO@SNonbQZ6PUGjBz@D81BZPjsr6awUUd@LgpRdgo6why5fJmaERj84V23y7lwBQErhcUnNG8kdz0VNogyyupufYbTpdJimtWwZ3Kgg9WBB7Rgxq/kk4F2epIRN0Ne73f/wY)

```java
// let's assume that we have a square matrix
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
            {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}};

    System.out.println(isSymmetric(matrix)); // true
    System.out.println(isSymmetricR(matrix, 1, 0)); // true
}
```

```java
// iterative version
static boolean isSymmetric(int[][] matrix) {
    return IntStream.range(1, matrix.length)
            .allMatch(i -> IntStream.range(0, i)
                    //intermediate output
                    .peek(j -> System.out.println("i=" + i + ",j=" + j))
                    .allMatch(j -> matrix[i][j] == matrix[j][i]));
}
```

```java
// recursive version
static boolean isSymmetricR(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
    if (i < matrix.length && j < i) {
        //intermediate output
        System.out.println("i=" + i + ",j=" + j);
        if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[j][i]) {
            if (j == i - 1) {
                return isSymmetricR(matrix, i + 1, 0);
            } else {
                return isSymmetricR(matrix, i, j + 1);
            }
        } else {
            // the first mismatch, the
            // matrix is not symmetric
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // if reached this point,
        // the matrix is symmetric
        return true;
    }
}
```

The intermediate output is the same in both cases:

```
i=1,j=0
i=2,j=0
i=2,j=1
i=3,j=0
i=3,j=1
i=3,j=2
i=4,j=0
i=4,j=1
i=4,j=2
i=4,j=3
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to remove rows and columns containing only zeros from a 2d matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66720998/15402945)</sup>